# Echo'ing into a file only works with root and not sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, echo

I have a directory `/sys/class/leds/` with the file `bananapro\:green\:usr/trigger` that controls an (green) onboard led. The contents of this file just contains the modes for the led. As root, I can run `echo "default-on" > /sys/class/leds/bananapro\:green\:usr/trigger` and have the led turn on. If I try to do this from a different user, I get the following responce from bash;

```
bash: /sys/class/leds/bananapro:green:usr/trigger: Permission denied
```

I have tried also running using

```
sudo bash -c echo "<command>"
```

from the non root user (with sudo access)
Any recommendations on getting file permissions for users other than `root`

Answer (score 1):

Use `tee` to run sudo as normal user:

```
echo "default-on" | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/bananapro\:green\:usr/trigger
```